Reverse current blocking FET circuit for batteries, does it work?

Based off of a previous post found here, I've created this circuit below to simulate the reverse current coming back from an FET. I've replaced the switch with a NMOS that's controlled by the presence of the reverse current. However, when reverse current is active, the FET array block the returning current and the reverse current charges the load instead.

Does this mean that when two batteries are connected in parallel
(with my circuit installed at each battery), and battery1 sees a
reverse current due to a voltage difference between them, then
will only battery2 provide current the load and vice versa until
the two batteries equalize their voltages?
Will this broadly simulate the behavior of a diode in its reverse
current blocking capacity?
Is this kind of input generally bad for my load (dc-dc converter
feeding into a pi)?


Does this answer your question? Automatic Power Selection with MOSFET

Hi David, thanks for pointing me towards the post. The design you suggested there seems to be used for when one of the two batteries is detached from the circuit (which causes the other to be fed to load and vice versa). However, in my scenario, neither of the parallel batteries can be detached. I am looking for something like an ideal diode configuration with very low Vf, but without a controller/diode IC.

does it work with ideal components it does, but in the real world only sometimes it does.  the real question is  does it do what you need

Right now yes in the sense that it prevents reverse current from the battery, but I want to make sure that I am not misinterpreting its behavior. All I want is a lower Vf replacement for a schottkey essentially.

@Dave Tweed. I believe this is a different question: Reverse current blocking is different from a "power path" circuit.

@DavideAndrea: In what way does an "ideal diode" circuit fail to block current?

@ Dave Tweed It shouldn't. Unless it breaks due to too high a voltage, I suppose.
